# merge 2 JSON objects in GAS (no jquery)

Tags: json, google-sheets, javascript-objects

How can I merge 2 (structurally identical) JSON objects like this (in Google Spreadsheet script)?

```
{"records":[{"id":28100988,"work_text_reviews_count":13,"average_rating":"3.10"},{"id":10280687,"work_text_reviews_count":80,"average_rating":"3.87"}]}

{"records":[{"id":16135639,"work_text_reviews_count":0,"average_rating":"0.00"},{"id":17978337,"work_text_reviews_count":2414,"average_rating":"3.76"{"id":360721218,"work_text_reviews_count":4924,"average_rating":"3.98"}]}
```

After merge the result should be:

```
{"records":[{"id":28100988,"work_text_reviews_count":13,"average_rating":"3.10"},{"id":10280687,"work_text_reviews_count":80,"average_rating":"3.87"},{"id":16135639,"work_text_reviews_count":0,"average_rating":"0.00"},{"id":360721218,"work_text_reviews_count":4924,"average_rating":"3.98"}]}
```

Since this in Google Spreadsheets I can't use JQuery, and I've spent all day trying javascript solutions which I couldn't get working without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `concat`:

```
var json1 = {
  "records": [{
    "id": 28100988,
    "work_text_reviews_count": 13,
    "average_rating": "3.10"
  }, {
    "id": 10280687,
    "work_text_reviews_count": 80,
    "average_rating": "3.87"
  }]
}

var json2 = {
  "records": [{
    "id": 16135639,
    "work_text_reviews_count": 0,
    "average_rating": "0.00"
  }, {
    "id": 17978337,
    "work_text_reviews_count": 2414,
    "average_rating": "3.76"
  }, {
    "id": 360721218,
    "work_text_reviews_count": 4924,
    "average_rating": "3.98"
  }]
}


var json3 = json1.records.concat(json2.records);
```